# rbindlist in R - only keep columns that have a match

Tags: r, data.table

i have created an empty data.table and i am running a loop which fill it. Depending on what the user need, the empty data.table has more/less columns. On thee other hand, the loop has always the same amount of columns, which is often more than the data.table has.

Thus, my loop produces some columns that are not needed and I would like them to be discarded. Is this possible to somehow tell rbinlist to only keep the columns that are available in the empty data.table and discard the rest? At the moment R attaches all columns that do not have a match to the end of my empty data.table.

at the moment i use:

Comment: please provide reproducible example with dput()

Answer (score 1):

`data.table::rbindlist` doesn't support this, so you'll need a wrapper function, perhaps something like this:

```r
rbindlist2 <- function(L, ..., .names) {
  if (missing(.names)) .names <- colnames(L[[1]])
  L <- lapply(L, function(x) subset(x, select = .names))
  data.table::rbindlist(L, ...)
}
rbindlist2(list(data.table(a=1,b=2,d=4), data.table(a=4,b=5,c=6)), .names = c("a", "b"))
#    a b
# 1: 1 2
# 2: 4 5
```

**Updated**: to allow manual control of the column names to preserve.

Comment: what if the "reference" contains columns that are not in the second data.table, but i want to keep all reference columns?

Comment: at the moment i get an error: `Error in `[.data.table`(x, r, vars, with = FALSE) : 
  column(s) not found:`

Comment: Nneka, see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Following on from @r2evans this will deal with the case where original table has names that others do not:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist2 <- function(ref_dt, dt_list) {
  L <- lapply(seq_along(dt_list), function(i){
    dt_list[[i]][,setdiff(names(ref_dt), names(dt_list[[i]]))] <- NA
    return(dt_list[[i]])
    }
  )
  vecs_to_keep <- names(ref_dt)
  dt_l <- lapply(L, function(x) subset(x, select = vecs_to_keep))
  data.table::rbindlist(dt_l)
}
rf_dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2, d = 8)
list_dt <- list(data.table(a = 1, b = 2, l = 8), data.table(a = 4, b = 5,c = 6))

rbindlist2(rf_dt, list_dt)
```

Comment: what if the "reference" contains columns that are not in the second data.table, but i want to keep all reference columns?

Comment: @Nneka please see edit and upvote and accept it if it does what you require.